# Why does my button background get cut off in Firefox but not Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
html.darkBlue button {
   border-color: #cccccc;
   color: #222222;
   background: linear-gradient(#fafafc, #ededf0 50%, #e3e3e5 50%, #e8e8eb);
}
.question-marking-buttons button {
   padding: 0.4rem;
   height: 1.4rem;
   line-height: 1.4rem;
   margin-right: 0.5rem;
   float: left;
   width: 4rem;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<button>Mark</button>
```

In Google Chrome the button background extends from the top of the button to the bottom like this:

```
xxxxxxxxx
x       x
x Mark  x
x       x
xxxxxxxxx
```

In Firefox it looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxx
x       x
x Mark  x
xxxxxxxxx
```

Can someone give me advice on why the background is getting cut off in Firefox but not Chrome?

Comment: What happens if you set `display: inline-block` on your button?

Comment: You're funny, i make a fiddle for you, for helpers... : http://jsfiddle.net/QwvqU/

Comment: Nothing happens in Firefox when I add display: inline-block to the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
OK a few reasons

First issue, is problem with height, width, and line-height.

Second issue, is that the reason buttons and divs are different sizes in Firefox and Chrome, is only because of the text size. Firefox makes slightly bigger text size.

For example, if you have a text size of 15px, well Firefox makes a larger 15px than Chrome does.

The way I fixed this on my own website, is by using **[cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)** for the text. Since cufon is an external font, it displays the exact same width on Firefox, Chrome, and every other browser. This solved my menubar width and button width cross-browser problems.

You should also use px or em instead of rem, just a tip.

---

**NOTE 1:** I hosted the necessary cufon files on `yourjavascript.com` for this example. However, you should either download those files and host on your own website, or create the files yourself from the [cufon website](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), and host the files on your own site.

**NOTE 2:** To get the font file to upload to cufon to create the cufon fonts file, just go into `C:\Windows\Fonts\` and find the font you want to use (i.e. `Arial`) and copy it to your desktop. Then upload that font file onto the cufon website for hosting. You can also download font files from google fonts or other sites, if you want different fonts to use with cufon.

---

**SUMMARY:**

**Problem 1:** line-height extends height
**Problem 2:** padding is wrong
**Problem 3:** firefox makes different size text. Use cufon to circumvent issue
**Problem 4:** needs padding-before hack
**Problem 5:** needs box-sizing hack. This prevents padding from being added to the width.
**Problem 6:** need to set css to button specifically, for good measure.

---

See my finished fix on jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/AxiCiNA/3

The code (same thing from the `jsbin` I created):

**page.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/319153210071/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/330149971117/thearialcufonfile.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <button id='one'>Mark</button>
        <button id='two'>Mark</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#one {
   border-color: #cccccc;
   color: #222222;
   background: linear-gradient(#fafafc, #ededf0 50%, #e3e3e5 50%, #e8e8eb);
}
button#two {
   padding: 1px 8px;
   margin: 0;
   margin-right: 9px;
   float: left;
   font: 15px 'Times New Roman, Serif';
   height: 25px;
   width: 50px;
   line-height: 10px;
   /* box-sizing hack for chrome */
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   /* box-sizing hack for firefox */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   /* box-sizing hack for opera */
   box-sizing: border-box;
   /* padding-before hack for chrome */
   -webkit-padding-before: 1px;
   -webkit-padding-after: 0;
   -webkit-padding-start: 1px;
   -webkit-padding-end: 0;
   /* padding-before hack for firefox */
   -moz-padding-before: 0px;
   -moz-padding-after: 0;
   -moz-padding-start: 1px;
   -moz-padding-end: 0;
   /* padding-before hack for opera */
   padding-before: 1px;
   padding-after: 0;
   padding-start: 1px;
   padding-end: 0;
}
```

**script.js**

```
Cufon.replace('#two', { fontFamily: 'Arial' });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking forward to your example.

Comment: ok, updated. I also added a few more css fixes including `margin-before`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of those two lines :

```
 padding: 0.4rem;
 height: 1.4rem;
```

That's too much padding for that height.

Try this

```
padding: 0;
height: 1.5rem;
```